# Does an RSS feed have to be an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I ask this because I see only two xml files in a wordpress blog, wlwmanifest.xml and default.xml and neither look like an rss feed. However I do see a php file called feed-rss2.php that looks like an rss feed. Everything I've ever read says that rss feeds have to be xml files. Am I wrong? Can they be php files with xml code inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just outputting XML code with XML headers. The actual file doesn't have to be an XML file, just the response has to be text/xml and contain XML output. You can do the same for things like CSS files... anything really.

Comment: That is AWESOME because that means I don't have to figure out how to output the output of the php file I created to a file with an xml extension. And you must be right, cause I opened the rss.php file in firefox and it read it just fine. Just hope iTunes doesn't have any special conditions when submitting a feed...Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a file extension in HTTP.

A client requests a URI from a server. The server responds with a `Content-Type` HTTP header that says what type of file it is sending back, and the file in the HTTP body.

The client doesn't care (and can't know) if the server generated that response by reading a static file, by running a program, or by some other means.

There is no difference to the client between a PHP program that outputs XML and a static XML file.

Answer (score 0):

The RSS Readers would be looking only on the client side, not the server side. In the wordpress installations, the `feed-rss2.php` is a PHP File, processed by the server, by giving the correct headers in the format:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

So that the readers get to know that it is a XML file and not a PHP file. As [Robbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262923/robbo) said, the actual file doesn't have to be an XML file, just the response has to be text/xml and contain XML output.

Even the same case with the styles. If you see the wordpress's `style.php`, it would have something like:

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
include($theme . "/style.css");
```

So that, it uses PHP's power to read the appropriate file and display the output in the same URL. Easy isn't it?